# UIScrollView zoom after rotation

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

Allright, i have a UIScrollView with some drawings inside. the zoom and scroll works fine until i zoom in and then rotate. after the rotation zoom is fine but when i zoom back my drawings shrink more than i intend them to.
So basically, when i zoom out after rotation the view gets smaller than the screen.. how can i fix this problem ? any idea ?

I tried `_scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;` but not working after the rotation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tired to set min/max zoom scale on the UIScrollView ? Assuming you have a reference to the UIScrollView you can set the minimum zoom scale. This will ensure that when you zoom out you drawings won't shrink more than you want.

`scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.00;`